# jQuery fade in jumping when used with overlay

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a "scroll down" button added to my site. This scroll down button I would like to gradually decrease in opacity the further I scroll from the top of the page. I am facing two issues- firstly, when I use a standard fade in and out, the items opacity jumps as it passes to the higher z-index of the opacity layer when fading back in (as you scroll up), using this js:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
  {
    $('.godown').fadeOut();
  }
  else
  {
    $('.godown').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/YzqKXQK)

I then tried to implement it so that the further away from the top I was, the more gradual it would reduce the opacity- in a hope to try and solve the jumping. However, I cannot get this code to work at all:

```
var target = $('.godown'),
  targetHeight = target.outerHeight();

$(document).scroll(function(e) {
  var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;

  if (scrollPercent >= 0) {
    target.css('opacity', 1 - scrollPercent);
  }
});
```

Any help appreciated on trying to combine these two methods, whilst avoiding the jumping opacity seen in the codepen.

Comment: In your codepen when clicking the arrow - well, as you can see nothing happens.

Comment: Normally this would be linked to an id that it'd jump to, but it's functionality is unimportant for the purposes of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

We can get

- the height of the page
- our position (which at start will be max and goes down)
- and on scroll, get a factor by dividing position be document height
- we can round this number (not necessary)
- use this number as the opacity (this will never be greater 1 or less than 0)
- you can further tune this number to your liking

working **snippet**:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var docHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
  var x = docHeight;
  var pos = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  var opacity = docHeight - pos;

  x = pos / docHeight;
  document.getElementById("anchorP").innerHTML = x.toFixed(2);
  $('a').css('opacity', x);

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400);
.godown a {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1vh;
  left: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font: normal 400 20px/1 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.godown a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

#scroller a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

#scroller a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="background-color: red;">
  <section id="scroller" class="godown">
    <div>
      <a href="#anchor"><span></span>Scroll <p id ='anchorP'><p></a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this gets me part of the way there- however, how would I adjust it so that the opacity is 0 once it reaches half way down the page to a specified anchor point rather than the bottom?

Comment: If the point is at 50% of the height of the page, multiply x by 0.5... if your point is at 80% of the height of the page, multiple x by 0.8... and so on and so forth

Comment: Is there not a way of doing this to a set anchor point, I feel as if that way won't scale well on different devices.

Comment: To get this factor (Let’s call it ‘y’), get location of your anchor point and divide that by total height of the document... and then simply x * y/100; this y is what I wrote in my comment above, it could be 50% or 80%